# Who produces 404-Not Found even if server is not available

Tags: http

In `[RFC-2616]`[1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), it is stated as

> 10.4.5 404 Not Found: The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI

What if server itself is not available? Why do I see `404` then ?

For example: I have requested `https://localhost:8080/helloworld.html` and `localhost` is down at the moment. As per my understanding, `404` is a status code generated by server and if server itself is not available then who produces `404` .

Comment: This depends on your setup. I don't have any server listening on the port 8888 for example and Chrome complain about "localhost refused to connect." as expected.

Comment: @MargaretBloom so if I see 404 in this case then it is generated by browser itself?

Comment: The 404 is generated by a server. You have a server running. Unless you have some browser that likes to show unusual errors page.

Comment: @MargaretBloom To be more specific, I have tomcat setup at localhost and port 8080 and I have not yet started the server. so server is not available. what if I see 404 in this case?

Comment: I can't tell what's going on on your machine. There are plenty of [tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) to see your network status, including listening ports and associated processes.